How to open a container for requests from outside
I am studying docker and I encountered the following problem. I described docker compose which includes my application with database and pgAdmin. Then I execute the command
docker-compose up after which all containers are launched and access to them is carried out through localhost:{PORT}. The thing is that I want to open access to one of the containers so that the client can send requests to my application.
docker-compose.yml
version: '3.8'

services:
  app:
    image: 'docker-spring-boot-postgres:latest'
    build:
      context: .
    container_name: app
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://db:5432/database
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=username
      - SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=password
      - SPRING_JPA_HIBERNATE_DDL_AUTO=update

  db:
    image: 'postgres:16.4-alpine'
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    container_name: db
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=username
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password
      - POSTGRES_DB=database

  pgadmin:
    container_name: pgadmin
    image: 'dpage/pgadmin4:8.10'
    restart: always
    environment:
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: email@admin.com
      PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: password
    ports:
      - "5050:80"

Photo form docker desktop

After launching all containers, when entering the command docker ps I get the following data
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE                                COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                           NAMES
6f9430a14763   docker-spring-boot-postgres:latest   "java -jar hearthgue…"   43 minutes ago   Up 21 seconds   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp          app
0f03246b006e   postgres:16.4-alpine                 "docker-entrypoint.s…"   43 minutes ago   Up 22 seconds   0.0.0.0:5432->5432/tcp          db
fb8f2f4103fd   dpage/pgadmin4:8.10                  "/entrypoint.sh"         43 minutes ago   Up 22 seconds   443/tcp, 0.0.0.0:5050->80/tcp   pgadmin

All my containers have IP localhost, which is why when I launch them, only I have access and other people cannot get data. I want to make the app container public so that when I launch the container on my computer, another person can easily connect to the server and get data. Please help me.

Perhaps not related to the question but I would suggest you read about some cyber security before you start exposing yourself on the internet.

All your containers are exposed to the network. You can see that from the PORTS column, in which the IP is 0.0.0.0, which means all bound IPs.
The issue is probably a firewall on the computer you are running this, or the way you are running docker e.g. docker on mac and windows run on VMs. Also you might need to do port forwarding on your home router so requests get forwarded the server.
Might be better to ask this on the super-user stack exchange site as this is more of a network-related issue rather than programming.
And as @darclander mentioned, the moment you open a port to the internet, you'll start being attacked.
